# Dynamically change header button icon on page change, jQuery mobile 1.4.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Ok so this should be simple but nothing seems to work...

```
 <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <h1 class="ui-title" id="headertitle"></h1>
        <a class="ui-btn-left ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-mini" id="leftButton" onclick="alert('this');" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
 </div>
```

I have tried the following in the pageshow, page create and page before show events on page change in jQuery mobile:

```
$('#leftButton').data("icon", "grid");
$('#leftButton').jqmData("icon", "grid");
$('#leftButton').attr("data-icon", "grid");
```

None of which seem to work. So how do you change a header button icon to suit each page?

Comment: You can try something like `$('#leftButton').attr("data-icon", "grid").trigger("refresh");`

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem in jsfiddle and share the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery mobile has a button widget as well as dom elements styled to look like buttons. In your case the Anchor is just styled, so you can simply switch out classes:

```
<a id="leftButton" href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all">No text</a>

$( "#leftButton" ).on("click", function(){
    $(this).removeClass("ui-icon-gear").addClass("ui-icon-grid");
});
```

If you want to use a widget, then you can set the icon option in code (http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#option-icon):

```
<input id="btnWidget" type="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" value="Icon only" />

$( "#btnWidget" ).on("click", function(){
    $(this).button( "option", "icon", "grid" );
});
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ek8go439/)** of both techniques

Comment: Great, the first option works nicely, haven't tried the second but what about custom icons? Is that possible with either of the above approaches?

Comment: ignore comment above, just used ui-icon-**mycustomicon** many thanks.

Comment: @OliverJ90, you are welcome. You are correct, custom icons are just classes that can be swapped out too.